# Multer array local images not saving in express or react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have a MERN app and I'm trying to save files locally, however, nothing seems to be working.

I'm trying to upload an array of multiple `images`.

Here is what I have code wise:

collection.js

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

let collectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  reference: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  images: [{ filename: String, mimetype: String, data: Buffer }],
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  year: Number,
  categoryName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  sold: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
});

collectionSchema.virtual("category", {
  ref: "category",
  localField: "name",
  foreignField: "categoryName",
  justOne: false
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("collection", collectionSchema);
```

collectionsController.js POST method

```js
/* POST create a collection */
module.exports.createCollection = [
  ...validations,
  (req, res) => {
    // Get validation errors from the request
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    // Return the errors
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(422).json({ error: errors.array() });
    }

    Collections.findOne({ _id: req.body.id }).then(function(collection) {
      Collections.create({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        reference: req.body.reference,
        images: req.body.images,
        price: req.body.price,
        year: req.body.year,
        categoryName: req.body.categoryName,
        sold: req.body.sold
      })
        .then(function(collection) {
          res.status(201).json(collection);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error(error);
          res.status(500).send(error);
        });
    });
  }
];
```

routes

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require("passport");
const collection = require("../controllers/collectionsController");
const multer = require("multer");
const GridFsStorage = require("multer-gridfs-storage");
const crypto = require("crypto");

const authenticate = passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false });

// Create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = file.originalname;
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: "uploads"
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

router.get("/", collection.index);
router.get("/:id", collection.getCollection);

// CRUD routes
router.post(
  "/create",
  authenticate,
  upload.single("images"),
  collection.createCollection
);
router.put("/:id", authenticate, collection.updateCollection);
router.delete("/:id", authenticate, collection.deleteCollection);

module.exports = router;
```

create component

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import swal from "sweetalert";

import AuthService from "../../Auth/AuthService";
import withAuth from "../../Auth/withAuth";
const Auth = new AuthService();

class Create extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      reference: "",
      images: [],
      price: "",
      year: "",
      categoryName: "",
      categorys: [],
      sold: false,
      titleErr: "",
      descriptionErr: "",
      referenceErr: "",
      imagesErr: "",
      priceErr: "",
      yearErr: "",
      categoryErr: ""
    };
  }

  validate = () => {
    let titleErr = "";
    let descriptionErr = "";
    let referenceErr = "";
    let imagesErr = "";
    let priceErr = "";
    let yearErr = "";
    let categoryNameErr = "";

    // Title validation
    if (!this.state.title) {
      titleErr = "Please enter a title";
    }

    // Description validation
    if (!this.state.description) {
      descriptionErr = "Please enter a description";
    }

    // Reference validation
    if (!this.state.reference) {
      referenceErr = "Please enter a reference";
    }

    // Images validation
    if (!this.state.images) {
      imagesErr = "You must have at least one image";
    }

    // Price validation
    if (!this.state.price) {
      priceErr = "Please enter a price";
    }

    // Year validation
    if (!this.state.year) {
      yearErr = "Please enter a year";
    }

    // Category validation
    if (!this.state.categoryName) {
      categoryNameErr = "Please enter a category";
    }

    // Render validations
    if (
      titleErr ||
      descriptionErr ||
      referenceErr ||
      imagesErr ||
      priceErr ||
      yearErr ||
      categoryNameErr
    ) {
      this.setState({
        titleErr,
        descriptionErr,
        referenceErr,
        imagesErr,
        priceErr,
        yearErr,
        categoryNameErr
      });
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("/api/category")
      .then(res => this.setState({ categorys: res.data }))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  onTitleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ title: event.target.value });
  }

  onDescriptionChange(event) {
    this.setState({ description: event.target.value });
  }

  onReferenceChange(event) {
    this.setState({ reference: event.target.value });
  }

  onImagesChange(event) {
    this.setState({ images: event.target.value });
  }

  onPriceChange(event) {
    this.setState({ price: event.target.value });
  }

  onYearChange(event) {
    this.setState({ year: event.target.value });
  }

  onCategoryNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ categoryName: event.target.value });
  }

  onSoldChange(event) {
    this.setState({ sold: event.target.value });
  }

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const isValid = this.validate();
    const {
      title,
      description,
      reference,
      images,
      price,
      year,
      categoryName,
      sold
    } = this.state;

    let config = {
      headers: { Authorization: "bearer " + Auth.getToken() }
    };

    let body = {
      title,
      description,
      reference,
      images,
      price,
      year,
      categoryName,
      sold
    };

    const file = document.getElementById("images").files;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(body, file);

    if (isValid) {
      axios
        .post("/api/collections/create", formData, config)
        .then(result => {
          swal({
            title: "Success",
            text: "You have created a collection",
            icon: "success",
            button: "OK"
          });
          this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          swal({
            title: "Error",
            text: `${error}`,
            icon: "error",
            button: "Try again"
          });
        });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const {
      title,
      description,
      reference,
      images,
      price,
      year,
      categoryName,
      sold
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <div className='block md:flex md:flex-column h-full'>
          <div className='p-12 w-full text-center text-gray-800'>
            <h1 className='title mb-10'>Create a collection</h1>

            <form
              className='w-full m-auto max-w-lg'
              onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
              encType='multipart/form-data'
            >
              <div className='flex flex-wrap mb-4'>
                <label htmlFor='title'>Title:</label>
                <input
                  type='text'
                  name='title'
                  value={title}
                  onChange={this.onTitleChange.bind(this)}
                  placeholder='Title'
                />

                <p className='mt-2 text-red-500 text-xs'>
                  {this.state.titleErr}
                </p>
              </div>

              <div className='flex flex-wrap'>
                <label htmlFor='description'>Description:</label>
                <textarea
                  type='text'
                  name='description'
                  className='h-64'
                  value={description}
                  onChange={this.onDescriptionChange.bind(this)}
                  placeholder='Content'
                ></textarea>

                <p className='mb-4 text-red-500 text-xs'>
                  {this.state.descriptionErr}
                </p>
              </div>

              <div className='flex flex-wrap mb-4'>
                <label htmlFor='reference'>Reference:</label>
                <input
                  type='text'
                  name='reference'
                  value={reference}
                  onChange={this.onReferenceChange.bind(this)}
                  placeholder='reference'
                />

                <p className='mt-2 text-red-500 text-xs'>
                  {this.state.referenceErr}
                </p>
              </div>

              <div className='flex flex-wrap mb-4'>
                <label htmlFor='images'>images:</label>
                <input
                  type='file'
                  multiple
                  name='images'
                  value={images}
                  onChange={this.onImagesChange.bind(this)}
                  id='images'
                ></input>

                <p className='mt-2 text-red-500 text-xs'>
                  {this.state.imagesErr}
                </p>
              </div>

              <div className='flex flex-wrap mb-4'>
                <label htmlFor='price'>Price:</label>
                <input
                  type='number'
                  name='price'
                  value={price}
                  onChange={this.onPriceChange.bind(this)}
                  placeholder='price'
                />

                <p className='mt-2 text-red-500 text-xs'>
                  {this.state.priceErr}
                </p>
              </div>

              <div className='flex flex-wrap mb-4'>
                <label htmlFor='year'>Year:</label>
                <input
                  type='number'
                  name='year'
                  value={year}
                  onChange={this.onYearChange.bind(this)}
                  placeholder='Year'
                />

                <p className='mt-2 text-red-500 text-xs'>
                  {this.state.yearErr}
                </p>
              </div>

              <div className='flex flex-col mb-4'>
                <label htmlFor='categoryName'>Category</label>

                <div className='relative'>
                  <select
                    name='categoryName'
                    value={categoryName}
                    onChange={this.onCategoryNameChange.bind(this)}
                  >
                    <option>N/A</option>
                    {this.state.categorys.map(category => (
                      <option key={category._id} value={category.name}>
                        {category.name}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </select>

                  <div className='pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center px-2'>
                    <svg
                      className='fill-current h-4 w-4'
                      xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                      viewBox='0 0 20 20'
                    >
                      <path d='M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z' />
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className='flex flex-col mb-2'>
                <label htmlFor='sold'>Sold?</label>

                <div className='relative'>
                  <select
                    name='sold'
                    value={sold}
                    onChange={this.onSoldChange.bind(this)}
                  >
                    <option value='false'>No</option>
                    <option value='true'>Yes</option>
                  </select>

                  <div className='pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center px-2'>
                    <svg
                      className='fill-current h-4 w-4'
                      xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                      viewBox='0 0 20 20'
                    >
                      <path d='M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z' />
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className='flex'>
                <button type='submit' className='btn w-full'>
                  Submit
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default withAuth(Create);
```

If I test creating a collection in postman I get the following

[image]

Any help in this would be great as it's been driving me up the wall all day trying to even get base local images saving, let alone S3.

I'm now getting this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I realized you are using `upload.single("images")` instead of `upload.array("images")` ...
https://github.com/expressjs/multer#arrayfieldname-maxcount

I created a very simple gist, hopefully it will get you on track:
https://gist.github.com/danikane/740fd36b100bebfc21620181936b8b53

First of all is your form multipart/form-data? Are you getting the files and are they saved on the file system in the destination folder you have defined with the filename you have defined?
First bypass your MongoDB saving logic, simplify your multer logic too - for example omit the filename function. I didn't quite get where saving exactly fails.

If you want to STORE the files in MongoDB you have 2 options:

1) Use GridFS to store the file (for files that may exceed 16MB)

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

https://www.settletom.com/blog/uploading-images-to-mongodb-with-multer

2) Store the buffer of the incoming file (with MemoryStorage option or fs.readFile the uploaded file)

https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information

Looks like you're trying to mix things. :)

Then again you can use the file system to store the files and just store the path and file properties in the **images** array in your MongoDB document.

You can also try [express-fileupload](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload), but I doubt your problem is really with multer.
Once you get it right you AWS S3 will be a breeze.

IMHO MongoDB is great all-rounder, I love it, however there might be better options for this task..

Comment: Files aren't being saved at all currently. I'm using heroku for the hosting so local image saving isn't an option as heroku doesn't support it. So it'll have to be either saving in the DB or S3. I'll take a look at the links and see what I can get done.

Comment: Do you see any errors in regards to the form / db structure that I'll need to change?

Comment: Well, I don't really know. I don't get what's the idea of collectionsController.js.
I'd either use Mongoose validation server-side or some validation library in the front-end if it's needed.
But I don't think this is related to your issue.

Comment: Can you try with:

```images: [{
  filename: String,
  mimetype: String,
  data: Buffer
}]
```
and pass data into those accordingly from the incoming file using MemoryStorage?

Comment: In the db schema?

Comment: Yes, collection.js. The field names are just an example though.

Comment: OK, so I've taken a shot at a few things, see the recent qustion updates.

Comment: Obviously I'm uploading other data as well not just images

Comment: I just realized you are using ```upload.single("images")``` instead of ```upload.array("images")```
https://github.com/expressjs/multer#arrayfieldname-maxcount

Comment: I was trying it both ways but I am looking to upload multiple images

Comment: OK update, so images are saving (that's for the gist), how do I go about rendering them? https://i.gyazo.com/71de11c9d0c9c2cd7c69437b4c0aa35d.png I have tried `<img src={collection.images[0].filename} alt='Time piece' className='w-64 object-cover m-auto' />` but no image is showing.

Comment: Also, I'm going to need to map over the images for a slider as well. https://i.gyazo.com/a377c79b9ddd1d0e13060da12bd2519d.png

Comment: Another update. I got AWS working and the images are being uploaded, is it possible to save the AWS file URLs as the filename in the DB? Or store the metadata of the file including the URL?

Comment: I have it setup like so in terms of uploading the files https://i.gyazo.com/4ca77a2f095443cb2aa437a3098fc091.png

Comment: Nevermind, just tried on the front-end, get a `.map` error https://i.gyazo.com/6078cac70c34889f87e5da75db7c2454.png